# Attempting to prove that the linear solution to an ODE is the unique solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I am working with an ODE of the following form:

$$y\left(x\right)=\frac{x-ay'\left(x\right)}{1+b y'\left(x\right)^{2}},$$

where $a,b>0$.

This equation clearly has a linear solution. I would like to show that this is the only solution. My intuition says this is the case, and I have been able to prove it in the special case in which $a=0$. Though, my proof in the special case in non-trivial and I am not sure it is the ideal approach, so I won't include it here.

Thanks

Comment: In case the right hand side is lipschitz continous, maybe you can apply Piccard Lindelöfs threorem? Although I am not sure here, because you have a square in $y'$, so you might end up with a square root after rearanging, which is not lipschitz continous.

Comment: My understanding is that Piccard Lindelof's theorem would prove that there is a unique solution for a given initial condition, whereas I want to show that the only solution that holds globally is the linear solution (which has no free parameters).

Comment: This is a [d'Alembert's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_equation), although if you only want linear solutions you could substitute $y=mx+c$ and solve for $m,c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y(x)=mx+c$ is not the most general solution, this can be seen by plugging it into the equation and you'll find it only works for certain $m$ and $c$.

As @user10354138 points out, this is a d'Alembert's equation:
\begin{align}
y=xf(p)+g(p)&;\qquad [y'_x=p]\\\\
f(p)=\frac{1}{1+bp^2},\quad g(p)&=\frac{-ap}{1+bp^2}.
\end{align}
To solve we will take the Legendre Transformation, $x=Y'_x=P$, $y=XP-Y$, $p=X$ to get
\begin{align}
XP-Y=f(X)P+g(X),
\end{align}
which is linear in $X$. Under the integrating factor $E(X)=-\smallint \mathrm dX/(X-f(X))$ we have
\begin{align}
Y=\frac{1}{E(X)}\left(C+\int\frac{g(X)E(X)}{X-f(X)}\mathrm dX\right).
\end{align}
Now, take $X$ to be a parameter for our parametric solution, it follows that
\begin{align}
X(t)=t,\quad Y(t)=\frac{1}{E(t)}\left(C+\int\frac{g(t)E(t)}{t-f(t)}\mathrm dt\right),\quad E(t)=-\int\frac{\mathrm dt}{t-f(t)}.
\end{align}
In terms of $x$ and $y$ we then have our general solution:
\begin{align}
x(t)=\frac{Y(t)+g(t)}{t-f(t)},\quad y(t)=\frac{tg(t)-f(t)Y(t)}{t-f(t)}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you, I see how the general solutions can be derived and the linear solution is a singular solution. If I follow correctly, the general solutions here do not have domain over the full real line, and only the singular solution has such a domain.

Comment: Do you have any sense of how I could go about characterizing the interval of validity of these alternative solutions or at least proving that they explode, which seems to be the case numerically (perhaps I should start a new question)? Thanks!